# Quick Links add on and Document add on in new SharePoint pages

Tags: document, modern-pages, new-experience, quick-links

I'm creating pages using "New SharePoint" instead of "Classic SharePoint" and I am having trouble with the following:

1) I have a couple of pages where I have the Quick Links add-on and each page should display different links inside that plugin, but they are all the same on each page.

2) I have a site where I cannot display documents inside Document add-on. I need to display an excel file inside that Document add-on, but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

In case anyone is not sure what I am referring to, here is a screenshot of the two, above-mentioned, add-ons:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is working for you now. 
In my tenant both the document viewer and the quick-links issues you report are fixed (at present).

My guess is that they were regressions in the background code and have been fixed up since May when you had the issue.

D